# Static web with decorator like sitemesh

Tags: javascript

I started with a project using Spring MVC, and sitemesh for decorator, now the specs has changed and they want to move the back-end out of the front end, and

I would prefer to split the GUI of this to a static web which will call the other back-end API, so if I do that, it mean the static web will be plain HTML,CSS and JS.

So I just wonder is there any libraries out there can do something similar to sitemesh (for example if I use angular so they can build a static web with heap of components stuff but that require more rework for me)

I am looking for something similar which help me declare all of the css and js libraries in one file, and inside the "body" tag I just need to render different pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XMLHttpRequest as a part of a decorator.

Request specific page, and receive it as 'document', extract dom from XHR result and paste them using DOMObject.appendChild(node) or DOMObject.append(element).

Following code is an example, target page doesn't support https so, just error page is shown.(Visit https://bypass.isitea.net/default.php and allow connection before testing the code)

Be careful about CORS when using XMLHttpRequest.

```js
{
  let request = document.querySelector( "#request" );
  request.addEventListener( "click", function ( e ) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open( "GET", `https://bypass.isitea.net/default.php` );
    xhr.responseType = "document";
    xhr.addEventListener( "load", function ( event ) {
      let doc = xhr.response;
      let list = doc.querySelectorAll( "body *" );
      let target = document.querySelector( "#otherBody" );
      for ( const dom of list ) {
        target.appendChild( dom );
      }  
    } );
    xhr.send();
  } );
}
```

```css
div#otherBody {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba( 0, 128, 64, 0.5 );
}
```

```html
<span>https://bypass.isitea.net/default.php</span>
<input id="request" type="button" value="Request">
<div id="otherBody"></div>
```